# Return prime factors from int as input as an array

Tags: java, primes, factorization

I need to code an algorithm which takes an `int`, gets its prime factors, puts them into an array and returns them.

My code is the following.

```
public static int[] primfaktorzerlegung(int zahl) {
   int d=1; //this is the length of the array

   int[] result = new int[d]; //array has to be returned

   List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   for(int factor = 2; factor <= zahl; factor++) {
       while(zahl % factor == 0) {
           factors.add(factor);
           zahl = zahl / factor;
       }
   }

   for(int i : factors){ //trying to get every number of the arraylist
       int z = i;          
       result[d] = z; //trying to put the numbers of the arraylist into the array result
       d++;           //makes the array dimension one higher
   }
   return result; //returns the array

}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
at: result[d] = z;
```

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually increasing the size of the array by incrementing `d`. Once you have allocated the array, its size is fixed.

You can do this instead:

```
public static int[] primes(int number) {
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int factor = 2; factor <= number; factor++) {
        while (number % factor == 0) {
            factors.add(factor);
            number = number / factor;
        }
    }
    return factors.stream().mapToInt(n -> n.intValue()).toArray();
}
```

The `stream()` method exposes the `ArrayList` as a `Stream`, which allows you do use nice methods to manipulate collections. One of them is `mapToInt`, which allows you do apply a function to each element in the stream. You apply the function that takes an `n` and returns whatever comes in the body (the part after the `->`). In particular, since you are putting together a collection of *boxed* `Integer`s, you have to unbox them into `int`s (more on boxing [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html%5C)). The `intValue()` method does exactly that. Finally, you return an `int[]` by calling `toArray()` on it. In practice, you are saying: apply `intValue()` to each item in the list and return the resulting array.

Note that I took your main logic as is, I didn't go into the correctness of how you are computing prime factors.

Comment: thanks a lot. i will try to understand the code :) its working tho

Comment: I added an explanation about the last line, which is the only part I really added on top of your code.

Comment: Thank you so much! Guess i need to look at streams after this. Really detailed and good explanation :)